# Killer Apps architecture description

Tags: architecture

Some weeks ago a friend of mine showed me a website where the architecture of the most popular websites is explained and described (youtube, amazon,facebook) and it also showed some interesting statistics about them.

Does anyone know where can I find this information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was it [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/)? specifically, the [Real Life Architectures](http://highscalability.com/links/weblink/24) section?

-John

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be **http://highscalability.com/**